# Determine the roots of equation if possible

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

How to determine the roots of equation using numerical methods? I have this particular equation: $$\arctan(e^x)=\ln \left(\sqrt{\frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}}\right)$$
In my solution I have that this equation has no real roots.
So, my question is how do we determine the real roots of equation when it is not possible to do it using simple algebra? Also, how can we determine whether or not the equation has real roots? I know Newton-Rhapson's numerical method, but don't know how to apply it on this equation.

Thanks for replies.

Comment: The left-hand side is positive, and the right-hand side is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do to use numerical methods to find the root of a real function $f(x)$. Note that numerical methods practically always assume that the function is continuous near the root.

First I use a graph or other methods to find points $a$ and $b$ where $f(a)<0<f(b)$ and $f$ is continuous between $a$ and $b$. Then I am guaranteed that a root exists. If I know little else about the function I use the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) which is slow but certain to work in reasonable conditions. If I know $f'$ and it seems likely to work, I use Newton-Raphson. If I know $f'$ but I have reason to believe that Newton-Raphson may not work, I use a hybrid method (see [page 366 here](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c9-4.pdf)).

These methods will not work in your example, since the function found by subtracting the right-hand side from the left-hand side is always positive.

If I cannot find such points $a$ and $b$ but I have good reason to believe that a root exists between points $c$ and $d$, I use a minimization (for $f$ positive) / maximization (for $f$ negative) method to find the root. This works if the root is a double root; i.e. the graph acts like a parabola whose vertex is on the $x$-axis. I usually use the [golden section search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search), which is slow but safe.

This also does not work in your example, since the minimum is well above zero. Newton-Raphson fails in many cases, but it certainly fails in cases like yours where there is no root. Trying the minimization routines would show that.

Comment: Such an extensive answer, when equality trivially cannot hold?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I was answering his questions "How to determine the roots of [an] equation using numerical methods?" and "how do we determine the real roots of equation when it is not possible to do it using simple algebra?" Those questions (at least the second) go beyond the particular equation given so I thought they were worth answering. I also  used numeric methods to give a heuristic answer to "how can we determine whether or not the equation has real roots?"

Comment: I understand your point, fine.